# Ошибка name 'print' is used prior to global declaration

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я пытаюсь модернизировать ф-ю print, что бы в случае условия все ф-и print в скрипте писали в файл.

Код:

```
def print_to_file(*txt, output_file):
    with open (file, 'w') as f:
        original_print(*txt, file = output_file)

if cond:
    original_print = print
    global print
    print = print_to_file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Инструкция global должна писаться до обращения к переменной. Это повышает удобность чтения кода, и никак не влияет на исполнение. В данном случае можно написать вот так и ничего не поменяется:

```
def print_to_file(*txt, output_file):
    with open (file, 'w') as f:
        original_print(*txt, file = output_file)

if cond:
    global print
    original_print = print
    print = print_to_file
```

Comment: Вне функций `global` не нужно, глобальный `print` перезапишется и так.